# How to get Current Logged Internet Explorer User Name and Domain Name

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, javascript, sharepoint-server, windows-authentication

I need to get user details before hitting the SharePoint Server page.

User hitting sharepoint page(https://spxy) then I redirect to https://spxy/_layouts/TestHandler.ashx via httpmodule.

I need to get IE User logged in Name in the http handler page.

Example:

> XYZ Domain -- Test User -- John
>
> ABC Domain -- Test User -- Alex
>
> Contoso Domain -- Test User -- Tom

I just logged in windows login as Administrator, If I login in the  IE using john then I need to his domain name and user name.

Answer (score 3):

You can use JSOM by javascript like two different ways:

```
Using sp.js _spPageContextInfo.userLoginName
```

Or you could use **REST**

```
function getCurrentUser() {
    var endpointUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + '/_api/web/currentuser';
    return $.ajax({
            url: endpointUrl,
            method: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
            headers: {   
             "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
            } 
        }); }
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to get logged in user name

```
SPWeb site = SPControl.GetContextWeb(Context);
SPUser user = site.CurrentUser;
string strUserName = user.LoginName;
```

or you can use

```
SPWeb web = SPControl.GetContextWeb(this.Context);
string userName = web.CurrentUser.LoginName;
```

or you also can use

```
string userName = this.Context.User.Identity.Name;
```